# https not found in entitlement: react native

Tags: ios, react-native, keychain

When attempting login on our react native app we were getting the following:

`https not found in com.apple.developer.associated-domains entitlement`

We didn't find a SO post on this, so adding our solution as an answer below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to add the following to our .entitlements:

```
<key>keychain-access-groups</key>
<array>
    <string>{DEVELOPMENT_TEAM}.{APP_ID}</string>
</array>
```